# Generalizing valuations

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, valuation-theory

Let $F$ be a field, and let $\Gamma$ be a totally ordered abelian group. A valuation is a group homomorphism $v : F \to \Gamma$ such that $v(x + y) \geq \min(v(x), v(y))$. On the other hand, a valuation ring $O \subseteq F$ is a ring such that for every $x \in F^\times$, we have $x \in O$ or $x^{-1} \in O$. It is classical that the valuations on a field (up to equivalence) are in bijective correspondence with the valuation rings of that field.

Valuation theory also has important applications in number theory (since valuations correspond to prime ideals in a number field), and to algebraic geometry (because they correspond to points in affine space, among other reasons).

My question is: what work has been done to generalize valuations? The definition of a valuation makes sense without any modification if $\Gamma$ is an abelian lattice-ordered group instead of an abelian ordered group, and there are plenty of integral domains people care about that are not valuation rings. Have people studied "valuation-like" structures where the definition of a valuation is tweaked or generalized in some way? Have people studied "valuation-like rings" where *that* definition is tweaked or generalized in some way? Are there established correspondences between generalized valuations and generalized valuation rings?

Comment: In the work "Mori domains and commutative rings with CCT" M. Roitman studies what he calls semivaluation. Here the value group is replaced by a partially ordered semigroup. He tries to investigate the Mori property of domains by this.

Comment: There is a notion of pseudovaluation introduced by Davis, Langer and Zink in "Overconvergent Witt vectors". Rings with pseudovaluations have nice properties. They are used to study overconvergence in $p$-adic cohomology theories, such as Monsky--Washnitzer cohomology.

Comment: @DanielW. your answer is exactly what I was going for. I am also intrigued by the connection between pseudovaluations and Witt vectors. Thank you both.